# Async reading of large Cassandra table using Scala / Phantom-DSL

Tags: scala, phantom-dsl

I have an issue reading a table containing >800k rows. I need to read the rows from top to bottom in order to process them.

I use Scala and Phantom for the purpose.

Here is how my table look.

```
CREATE TABLE raw (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    b1 text,
    b2 timestamp,
    b3 text,
    b4 text,
    b5 text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

So far I've tried to read the table using:

```
def getAllRecords : Future[Seq[row]] = select.fetch
```

or the more fancy Play Enumerator and combine it with a Iteratee

```
def getAllRecords : Enumerator = select.fetchEnumrator
```

Nothing of this works, it seems like cassandra/driver/my program always tries to read all records upfront, what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried reviewing the code in the bigger read tests?

```
class IterateeBigReadPerformanceTest extends BigTest with ScalaFutures {

  it should "read the correct number of records found in the table" in {
    val counter: AtomicLong = new AtomicLong(0)
    val result = TestDatabase.primitivesJoda.select
      .fetchEnumerator run Iteratee.forEach {
      r => counter.incrementAndGet()
    }

    result.successful {
      query => {
        info(s"done, reading: ${counter.get}")
        counter.get() shouldEqual 2000000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is not something that will read your records upfront. In fact we have tests than run more than one hour to guarantee sufficient GC pauses, no GC overhead, permgen/metaspace pressure remains within bounds, etc.

If anything has indeed changed it is only in error, but this should still work.